# iOS7 won't trust linux computer

Tags: unix, ios

iPhone 4S  iOS7

Linux Mint

When I plug my phone into my Linux machine I get the following message "Trust this computer?"

No matter how many times I tap "Trust" the message comes up again.

I do not have this problem on my Win7 machine.

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things? I'm assuming that the "Trust this computer?" message is being displayed on the iPad. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish? Is your iPad jail broken?

Comment: Do you use iTunes on your windows machine or are you connecting to the phone using purely open source / third party drivers?

Comment: I'm running CrunchBang Linux waldorf on a Lenovo Thinkpad X100e and am trying to "trust" my connection between my Verizon iPhone 5 running iOS 7.0.3 (11B511) using a 100% official iPhone 5, 5c, and 5s Lightning Cable purchased directly from an Apple store (so no it's not a knock off) and no matter how many times I click "trust" it never does... However if I click "Don't Trust" it goes away, which I guess that's better some people have been experiencing. It looks like no one has found an answer yet, but I figured i'd share that I am still unable to fix this issue and in the hopes I might get mo

Comment: Here is a solution for linux. I assume the Ubuntu solution would work for Linux Mint. http://askubuntu.com/questions/414490/ubuntu-13-04-13-10-wont-trust-iphone

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a [bug in how Ubuntu interacts with the iOS device](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1207812). Currently this bug is unassigned, so it may take a while to have a fix.

The "Trust the currently connected computer" warning was [developed by Apple to alert users of bogus USB chargers that could compromise the device](http://allthingsd.com/20130801/ios-7-will-immunize-iphones-from-bogus-charger-attacks/).

Comment: This is going to be interesting. New alerts to signify that a live data connection is established - new alerts to alert to non-made for iPhone charging devices.

Answer (score 2):

the trust system is only stored if you have itunes installed and configured on the host system.  which Sucks.

so if you want to charge off of your work PC that doesnt have itunes, you are going to get prompted every time you try to plug it in.

I wish apple would've just smartened up and given us the 'you must unlock your device before you can access memory' type option that android has.

Comment: I asked a related question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107579/do-i-need-itunes-for-my-ios7-iphone-to-be-trusted-by-win-7-machine
Can you quote a definitive source that iTunes is required?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known iOS7 incompatibility in `libimobiledevice` versions 1.1.5 and earlier.  It was [reported to the developers](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/20) and [subsequently fixed](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/pull/26).  The fix is [part of the 1.1.6 release](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/8e96f2af5960f4f5e4b52e4d7fe4e3c0ff2fe655/NEWS#L38).

I can personally confirm that I saw [the same problem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1073003) under Fedora 20 with `libimobiledevice` 1.1.5.  Upgrading to [a test build](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2014-9092/libplist-1.11-2.fc20,libusbmuxd-1.0.9-2.fc20,libimobiledevice-1.1.6-2.fc20,usbmuxd-1.0.9-0.4.c24463e.fc20,ifuse-1.1.3-3.fc20,libgpod-0.8.3-2.fc20,upower-0.9.23-3.fc20,gvfs-1.18.3-3.fc20?_csrf_token=19462cd39594bbfd9c2340cd4b26fad2e145e213) of `libimobiledevice` 1.1.6 ought to fix the problem, but actually runs into some other [SELinux problems](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1073003#c14).

So assuming you don’t want to build from sources yourself, you need to convince your preferred Linux distribution to package, test, and ultimately ship `libimobiledevice` version 1.1.6 or later.