# Is iTunes required for iOS7 iPhone to trust PC with Windows 7?

Tags: itunes, security, windows, ios

Every time I connect my iPhone 5S (7.0.3, but have had this issue since 7.0 with both 5S and iPhone 4) to my computer (Latitude E6410 with Windows 7 Pro) I get prompted to Trust the computer. I trust it, and each time I reconnect the USB cable, the prompt returns.

I am not alone.

Googling this issue, it seems to affect a large number of Windows 7 users. There isn't a single solution that appears to work for everyone, but this one seems to have helped some:
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1567

However, it presupposes the presence of the AMDS service. I do not have this service, I presume because I do not have iTunes installed (and I would prefer not to install it). Nowhere could I find any information from Apple about whether iTunes is required for Trust. 
So my questions are:
(a) is it true the iTunes is required for establishing "Trust"?
and 
(b) if so, is there a workaround?

Note: this post (related to Linux) would imply to me that it should work without iTunes:
[iOS7 won't trust linux computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102417/ios7-wont-trust-linux-computer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely yes. You must have iTunes installed in order for the "Trust computer" option to be remembered.

What you can do is the following:

1. Temporarily install iTunes, do not run the program itself on your computer
2. Connect the iPhone and tap "Trust"
3. Go to the newly-created Apple Lockdown folder on Win 7 it is found here:

   C:\ProgramData\Apple\Lockdown
4. Copy the whole folder and paste it to a location you can remember (i.e. PC Desktop)
5. [Fully uninstall iTunes from your computer](http://www.copytrans.net/support/completely-uninstall-itunes-and-related-apple-software/)
6. [Install the iOS drivers without installing iTunes](http://www.copytrans.net/support/install-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad-drivers-without-installing-itunes/) (these drivers are needed in order for your PC to correctly recognize the iPhone
7. Restart PC if needed
8. Navigate to:  C:\ProgramData\
9. Add a new folder named "Apple" and inside it paste the "Lockdown" folder along with its contents.
10. This will keep your iPhone trust setting without the need for iTunes being installed

Comment: Firstly - great post and very useful information - thank you. Regarding "definitely yes" do you know whether Apple have stated this to be the case? 

On my work machine, this approach is not feasible (though it is for my home machine, so I will try it tonight).

Comment: Another comment/follow up: I have noticed that the Trust prompt doesn't appear immediately upon connection (generally at least). Is there something Windows is doing to prompt a 'lack of trust'? For example, trying to open the folders for viewing?

Comment: Regarding the "Trust" option not appearing immediately, it could be provoked by Plug and Play (once Windows tries to open up the iPhone after connect). 

Concerning my certitude, there's unfortunately no official Apple document confirming that you must have iTunes installed in order to remember the setting, however, Step 4. here hints that this is most probably the case: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5868.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted the answer. It is the best by far :) 
Would be interesting to approach the problem from the perspective of avoiding "mistrust"...

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature to prevent computers from automatically downloading content from your phone.

Simple fix in Windows:

1. Plug your phone into your computer.
2. Open Control Panel
3. If you are viewing by category, click on "Hardware and Sound", then "AutoPlay". If you are viewing by icon, just click "AutoPlay".
4. Scroll down to the bottom and find your iPhone/iPad.
5. In the dropdown select "Take no action".
6. Click the Save button.

You will no longer get the pop-up, and your phone will still charge.